# jQuery - Select element by class inside current row

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, html

I am generating a table with values from a database, the total of each columns is displayed at the end of the table.
I want to give the user the option of removing rows they don't want and have the total change accordingly.

Since the form will be submitted I already have hidden input elements added. I want to be able to get the value of a column in the row being removed and subtract it from the total, then display the new total.

I thought the best way would be to give each column a class name and for the specific row get the value of the class, as it is being deleted.

This is my table structure

```
    <tbody>';
for($i=0;$i<count($alto);$i++){
echo' <tr>
      <td>'.$key[$i].'</td>
      <td>'.$talk[0][$i].'<input type="hidden" class="bate" value="'.$talk[0][$i].'" name="0'.$key[$i].'"/></td>
      <td>'.$talk[1][$i].'<input type="hidden" class="vito" value="'.$talk[1][$i].'" name="1'.$key[$i].'"/></td>
      <td>'.$talk[2][$i].'<input type="hidden" class="hist" value="'.$talk[2][$i].'" name="2'.$key[$i].'"/></td>
      <td><button class="delete" type="button">Delete</button><td>
      </tr>';
}
echo '</tbody>
```

From my limited knowledge of jquery I think I would need something like this:

```
var exp = $(this).val('.vito');
```

Possibly I'm having traversing issues and I need to add a `.parents()` tag in there somewhere, but I'm not sure.

Comment: so you want to add bate, vito, hist for every tr and get the total?

Comment: What you're saying should work but I think your jQuery code is not going to get the result you want. If the `this` refers to the `<tr>` than you select the value of `.vito` with `$(this).find('vito').val();`

Answer (score 0):

Create function `calculate_total()` that calculate the table total and call it after deleting row :

```
function calculate_total(){
    var bate_total, vito_total, hist_total = 0;

    $("table").find('tr').each(function(){
        bate_total += parseInt( $(this).find('.bate').val() );
        vito_total += parseInt( $(this).find('.vito').val() );
        hist_total += parseInt( $(this).find('.hist').val() );
    });

    //Here you can assign the new totals to the columns that contain totals values
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Would this not work?
$(this).find('.className').val()

Comment: i'm not sure, you can try it.